# What fraction of a Sierpiński triangle is to the left of a given vertical line?

Tags: fractals, fractal-analysis

Let's say that we have a Sierpiński triangle of width 1 and height 1

I want to find the function $y(x)$ for $0<x<0.5$ that gives the fraction of the Sierpiński triangle contained in $[0,x]$

[image]

If we take each of the 3 main triangles as 1/3 of the fractal, then at $x=0.5$ we have 50% of the fractal to the left, or the leftmost triangle, more half of the upper triangle: $y(x)=1/3+1/2*1/3=1/2$

[image: 0.25]

At $x=0.25$ there is only half of the leftmost triangle, so the fraction is $y(x)=1/2*1/3=1/6$
It also can be calculated as the sum of each triangle to the left: $1/9*(1+1/3+1/3^2+1/3/^3+...)=1/6$

At $x=3/8$, by counting triangles, $y(x)=1/3$

There is a way to write a function of x? Only $0<x<0.5$ is needed

It looks like $y(x)=3y(x/2)$

By counting triangles, for

$x=(0, 1/16, 2/16, 3/16, 4/16, 5/16, 6/16, 7/16, 8/16)$

$y(x)=0/54,1/54, 3/54, 6/54, 9/54, 13/54, 18/54, 23/54, 27/54$

The last series is [OEIS A282720](https://oeis.org/A282720), described as "Number of nonzero terms in first n rows of the base-2 generalized Pascal triangle P_2"
Finding the Pascal triangle here is no surprising, becasue the Pascal triangle is famous for generating a Serpinsky triangle with his odd numbers:

[image: Serpinsky Paqscal triangle]

Every column of triangles is given by the OEIS [A007306](https://oeis.org/A007306) series, which has the formula

$$
 \sum_{k=0}^n \left[ \binom{n+k-1}{2k} \bmod 2 \right] = 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8,,,,
$$
[image]

I'm interested in finding some kind of integral of the triangle.

Comment: At $3/8$ is it not $5/6 \cdot 1/3$?

Comment: Also, they the triangles look to be equilateral, so width$\ne$height.

Comment: @mjw At 3/8, joining the 2 largest triangle pieces, it can be made an entire triangle of size 1/2 of the original, that represents 1/3 of all the points.

Comment: (5/18+1/18)⋅1/3 because there is an additional half 1/9 triangle above the 1/3 triangle. Each one of the 1/3 of the 1/3 triangle has 1/9 of the points

Comment: Oh, yes.  Seeing it now.  Somehow I missed a sixth.